# What software can I use to shape a shared Internet connection on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet

I have a laptop running Windows 7, which has two network cards, so I bridged the Ethernet and Wireless connections.

On a second laptop, which runs Windows XP, I set its default gateway to the IP of the bridged network.

The Windows 7 laptop with bridged network has access to the Internet via wireless. The Windows XP laptop can see the Internet through the bridged network.

How do I control the traffic through the Windows 7 machine? Is there a specific tool I can use to do this?

The ones I've found are specific to modems, and not to wireless connections. For wireless connections, I found a network load balancer, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Could you clarify the question?  It is a bit confusing and hard to understand what you are asking.  BTW, no downvote from me

Comment: @DaveM He is saying that Windows 7 PC is connected to internet with wireless/wired network. This internet connection is shared to XP machine using wired/wireless (opposite) network. Now, he wants to control access of internet connection which is shared with XP machine...

Comment: BTW,I am she :)

Comment: Oops.... sorry.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools like [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/)(Paid but one of the best I've used) or [pyShaper](http://www.freenet.org.nz/python/pyshaper/) (Free, does the job, no frills) to achieve this. It does not matter whether the network is wired or wireless.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool for this purpose is [Cisco Network Magic](http://purenetworks.com/download/) (Free & Paid both versions available). I can challenge any other tool with it.. Its easy to use & very-very powerful. It'll protect you from hackers too (If you've given your XP machine to them).